# Using JEP to run python code in java

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to run [this python library](https://github.com/nmarinsek/burst_detection) in java using [JEP](https://github.com/ninia/jep). I use the following code to send parameters to python.

```
NDArray<int[]> r = new NDArray<>(twf, 1, twf.length);
    NDArray<int[]> d = new NDArray<>(ndpw, 1, ndpw.length);
    jep.set("r", r);
    jep.set("d", d);
    jep.set("gamma", gamma);
    jep.set("smooth_win", smooth_win);
    jep.set("s", s);
    jep.set("n", n);
```

I end up with this error.

> < class 'AttributeError' >: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute '_to_mpmath'

I searched for the cause but found nothing.
What does this error mean?

EDIT:

In the library, there is a line of code which uses `Sympy` on NDarray. I guess the error is related to that line.

This is the line in the library:

```
import sympy.functions.combinatorial.factorials as c

return -np.log(np.float(c.binomial(d, r)) * (p ** r) * (1 - p) ** (d - r))
```

Comment: Does the same code work in a standard Python interpreter (instead of from Jep) or does it have the same error?

Comment: @ndjensen It has the same error.

Comment: Since the same error occurs with a standard Python interpreter, that indicates the error has nothing to do with Jep.  You could open a new question with more specifics on what you're doing with numpy and sympy.  Or you could update your ticket title and description and add tags for sympy and numpy to get better assistance.

Comment: @ndjensen Thanks, I figured it out.